# A question on combinatorics: if $p + q + r = 10$, find the number of possible combinations where the condition holds true.

Tags: combinatorics

If $ p + q + r = 10 $, find the number of possible combinations satisfying the equation. ( $p,q,r ≥ 0$)

---

PS -
As suggested by **Brian Moehring**, I used the '***stars and bars***' method.

We need the sum as $10$. We have to add $1$ ten times, to get 10. If we add two bars i.e., we are dividing them into p, q and r. So now in total there are $10 \ 1's$ and $2$ bars. We have to find the number of ways to arrange those $2$ bars in $12$ places. Hence, there are $\binom{12}{2}$ ways of selecting $p,\ q$ *and* $r$ to satisfy the equation.

Comment: You may want to search for "stars and bars"

Comment: @BrianMoehring Check PS.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio I mentioned that $p,q,r≥0$.

Comment: @rtybase My question has been answered and this can be closed

Answer (score 1):

The [Stars and Bars Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) Provide this formula that we can use here:

$$\binom {n+k-1}{n}=\binom {n+k-1}{k-1}$$

Using $n=10,k=3$

$$\binom {10+3-1}{3-1}=\binom {12}{2}=66$$

Answer (score 0):

Let do this:
$$p+q+r=10 \Longrightarrow (p+1)+(q+1)+(r+1)=13$$
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}p'=p+1>0 \\ q'=q+1>0 \\ r'=r+1>0 \\ \end{array}\right\}\Longrightarrow p'+q'+r'=1+...+1$$
That in right side of last equation we have $13$ ones. Since new variables are positive, any solution is equivalence to choose $2$ number of $+$ in right side as candidate for that we have at left side between variables. So the number of solution is:
$$\binom{12}{2}=66$$

Comment: I guess the different combinations are 8 1 1 , 7 2 1 , 6 3 1 , 6 2 2 , 5 4 1 , 5 3 2 , 4 4 2 , 4 3 3 - These are only 8.

Comment: @NoChance, You made $2$ mistakes. First you don't count $0$ included solution. Second you should count different orders.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.